# Linked List sentinel node to avoid reassigning pointer to first node

Tags: c, linked-list

**Theory**

When deleting a node from a linked list, pointers to the first node in the list will need to be updated if the node being deleted from the list is the first one.

**Background**

[Libevent: how to close all open sockets on shutdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332927/libevent-how-to-close-all-open-sockets-on-shutdown)

**Situation**

In my server application, a pointer to the first node in a linked list of socket connections is held in a struct holding data related to the context of the running instance, such as listening socket port and so on.   When a connection is closed, the related node in the linked list must be removed which means that the function which deletes the node must also access to the instance context struct.

**My first ideas were:**

Each connection node in the linked list has a pointer to the instance context struct.  *(Messy.)*

Global variable pointer to instance context struct.   *(Evil.)*

Then I had the idea to make the first node in the linked list a [sentinel node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) thereby avoiding the possibility that the first node would ever be removed and therefore side-stepping the need for the socket close function to have access to the instance context.

**Question**

Is this a suitable use of sentinel nodes or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Positing a simply implementation of your idea would greatly help.  Maybe post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Ideas: 1) Yes the sentinel idea can work 2) Still need a special delete() to delete the linked list along with the sentinel node. 3) Using this technique should code have _high_ percentage of empty lists is space inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any meta data about the linked list you'd like to store such as the length of the list? If so, you can store them in the sentinel node.